# In Tensorflow Classification, how are the labels ordered when using "predict"?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the MNIST handwritten numerals dataset to train a CNN.

After training the model, i use predict like this:

```
predictions = cnn_model.predict(test_images)
predictions[0]
```

and i get output as:

```
array([2.1273775e-06, 2.9292005e-05, 1.2424786e-06, 7.6307842e-05,
       7.4305902e-08, 7.2301691e-07, 2.5368356e-08, 9.9952960e-01,
       1.2401938e-06, 1.2787555e-06], dtype=float32)
```

In the output, there are 10 probabilities, one for each of numeral from 0 to 9. But how do i know which probability refers to which numeral ?

In this particular case, the probabilities are arranged sequentially for numerals 0 to 9. But why is that ? I didn't define that anywhere.

I tried going over documentation and example implementations found elsewhere on the internet, but no one seems to have addressed this particular behaviour.

Edit:

For context, I've defined my train/test data by:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = (np.expand_dims(train_images, axis=-1)/255.).astype(np.float32)
train_labels = (train_labels).astype(np.int64)
test_images = (np.expand_dims(test_images, axis=-1)/255.).astype(np.float32)
test_labels = (test_labels).astype(np.int64)
```

And my model consists of a a few convulution and pooling layers, then a Flatten layer, then a Dense layer with 128 neurons and an output Dense layer with 10 neurons.

After that I simply fit my model and use predict like this:

```
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS)
predictions = cnn_model.predict(test_images)
```

I don't see where I've instructed my code to output first neuron as digit 0, second neuron as digit 1 etc
And if i wanted to change the the sequence in which the resulting digits are output, where do i do that ?
This is really confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models work with numbers. Your classes/labels should be represented as numbers (e.g., `0, 1, ...., n`). The prediction is always indexed to show probabilities for class `0` at index `0`, class `1` at index `1`. Now in the MNIST case, you are lucky the labels are integers `0` to `9`. Suppose you had to classify images into three classes: *cars*, *bicycles*, *trucks*. You must represent those classes as numerical values. You can arrange it as you wish. If you choose this: {*cars*: **0**, *bicycles*: **1**, *trucks*: **2**}, in other words, if you label your cars as *0*, bicycles as *1*, and trucks as *2*, then your prediction would show probability for cars at index 0, bicycles at index 1 and trucks at index 2.

You could have also decided to choose this setting: {*cars*: **2**, *bicycles*: **0**, *trucks*: **1**}, then your prediction would show probability for cars at index 2, bicycles at index 0 and trucks at index 1, and so on.

The point is, you have to show your classes (as many as you have) as **integers** indexed from **0** to **n** where **n** is the `num_classes-1`. Your probabilities at prediction would be indexed as such. You don't have to tell the model.

Hope this is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you prepare your labels during training. With MNIST classification, usually, there are two different ways:

1. **One-hot Labels**: There are 10 labels in the MNIST data, therefore for each example (image), you create a label array (vector) of length 10 where all the elements are zero except the index corresponding to the digit that your input image is showing. For example, if your input image is showing the digit *8*, your label contains zeros everywhere except at the *8th* index (e.g. [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,*1*,0]). If your image is showing the digit *2*, your label would be something like [0,0,*1*,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and so on.
2. **Sparse Labels**: you just label each image directly by what digit it is showing, for example if your image is showing the digit *8*, your label is a single number with value 8.

In both cases, you could choose the labels however you want, in the MNIST classification it is just intuitive to use the labels 0-9 to show digits 0-9.

Thus, in the prediction, the probability at index 0 is for digit 0, index 1 for digit 1, and so on.

You could choose to prepare your labels differently. For example you could decide to show your labels as follows:

- label for digit 0: 9
- label for digit 1: 8
- label for digit 2: 7
- label for digit 3: 6
- label for digit 4: 5
- label for digit 5: 4
- label for digit 6: 3
- label for digit 7: 2
- label for digit 8: 1
- label for digit 9: 0

You could train your model the same way but in this case, the probabilities in the prediction would be inverted. Probability at index 0 would be for digit 9, index 1 for digit 8, and so on.

In short, you have to define your labels using integer indices, but it is up to you to decide and remember what index you chose to refer to which label/class.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but when i compare with my code, I have got labels as sparse coded whereas my network has an output layer of 10 nodes.

I have not defined a mapping from sparse to one hot anywhere. And that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Here's the link to the full code by the way:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YfyID92DCxlsYJBx2DlTOsiv1sMsWoKE

Comment: Yes, the tensorflow mnist dataset has the labels as sparse. labels are in the range 0 to 9, and they are also indexed as such. Therefore your prediction probabilities are also indexed as such. @ZainKhaishagi

Comment: When you say they are "indexed as such", what do you mean ? Where do i confirm this indexing or change it ? If i wanted the first output to be for digit 5, and second output for digit 8 etc, Where would i make such a change ? @Bashir-Kazimi

Comment: you would one-hot-encode digit 5 as such: [**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and digit 8 as [0,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and so on. In case of sparse labelling, you would just create an empty label array and at whichever index you have the digit *5*, you would set it as *0* and your digit *8* as *1*. and so on.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something fundamental, but i still don't follow. I've edited my question to add the code for how I've defined the test/train labels. They are sparse. After that  I simply fit the model and use predict. I still don't see where I instructed the model to output the results in the sequence that it outputs the results in.

Comment: I added explanations in a new answer as the comment couldn't contain all of it.